# Heroku worker does not work

Tags: django, heroku, worker

I am following Heroku's documentation about [workers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq) but never succeeded. There is a module `util.py` which will be run as a background job:

util.py:

```
import requests

def count_words_at_url(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return len(resp.text.split())
```

And to put utils.py to the worker's queue:

```
from utils import count_words_at_url
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn

q = Queue(connection=conn)
result = q.enqueue(count_words_at_url, 'http://heroku.com')
```

Question1: I would like to know how `q.enqueue(...)` works. I suppose that the first argument (`count_words_at_url` is the function name and the second argument ('`http://heroku.com`') will be used as the `count_words_at_url` function's argument.

If I am correct, why is `resp = requests.get(url)` necessary to get that argument? Why not just `return len(url.split())`?

EDIT:

Question 2: In order to be able to upload large files (Heroku always terminate such a request due to TIMEOUT), I would like to pass an HTTP request to a function which will be run as a background job:

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'upload/', views.upload),
]
```

`views.py`

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render(request, 'upload/upload.html')
    # POST
    q = Queue(connection=conn)
    q.enqueue(uploadFile, request)
    return render(request, 'upload/upload.html')

def uploadFile(request):
    # Upload files to Google Storage
    fileToUpload = request.FILES.get('fileToUpload')
    cloudFilename = 'uploads/' + fileToUpload.name
    conn = boto.connect_gs(gs_access_key_id=GS_ACCESS_KEY,
                           gs_secret_access_key=GS_SECRET_KEY)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(GS_BUCKET_NAME)
    fpic = boto.gs.key.Key(bucket)
    fpic.key = cloudFilename
    # Public read:
    fpic.set_contents_from_file(fileToUpload, policy='public-read')
```

`upload.html`:

```
...
<form method=post action="/upload/" enctype=multipart/form-data>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type=file name=fileToUpload><br><br>
  <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
...
```

I got the error message: `Cannot serialize socket object`
Turn out that I cannot pass a socket object to a forked process. Is there any other solution for large file uploading? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The clue to 1 is in the name of the function. It doesn't say "count words in URL", it says "count words *at* URL". In other words, it needs to go and get the page that is referenced by the URL, then count the words on it. That's what `requests.get()` does.

I don't understand what you're asking in point 2.

Comment: Got the idea. Thanks. I have re-edited Question 2. Any suggestions?